# Which user takes precedence domain controller administrator or local PC user created using user account for Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, users, local, controller

I need to know which user takes precedence, domain administrator or local PC user created using user account for Windows 2003.

Basically, what I want to know is if there is a service running using a local user account when the domain controller administrator logs off, then does the service stop running or does the local user takes over the control and keeps the service running in the background.

Please help me in getting this answered as I'm stuck up on this.

-Mahesh

Answer (score 3):

If the program is running as a service then it would keep running; interactive sessions have no bearing on services (other than being able to start/stop them or whatever).

If the program is running in the background of the session (like the system tray, or without user interaction entirely), when the session ends, so does the program. Logging off ends the session.

It works this way regardless of what kind of account is used/logged-in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question 100%; but services always run in the background and are not tied to any user being logged on *at all*.  You can boot the machine and never log on and the service will still be running.

The service (in the local services console) has a 'Log on' tab which is used to configure under what account the service runs (ie. your local user account, or more than likely the local system, or whatever you want).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the service is not dependent on who is logged in.  If you run services.msc you will see the list of services and the user account associated with the service in the "Log On As" column.  The service uses the specified account (and only that account) to login and do it's thing, it then runs in the background and any further authentication needs are provided by the specified account.